# ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR in production only with wifi

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx, actioncable

I have launched a new web some days ago and some users are getting this weird error on their chrome browsers:
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

This error only affects to some users and in some special conditions for example when they are using their wifi network, but using mobile data it works.

I have a Rails app with puma and nginx, all the http domains (www and non www) are redirected to https, I have an ssl certificate that is working fine.

In rails I have this config to force ssl and action cable

```
config.action_cable.url = 'wss://example.com/cable'
config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = ["https://example.com", "https://www.example.com"]
config.force_ssl = true
```

I also have this config in nginx for action cable, that `http://puma` looks weird but is working fine in most of cases

```
server {

  listen 443 ssl;

  ssl on;
  ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLS 1.3;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/crtbundle.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/_.example.com_private_key.key;
  server_name example.es;

...

  location /cable {
    proxy_pass http://puma;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }

...

}
```

Comment: There might be various reasons like firewalls in the clients network interfering with the connection or inconsistent setup on your site, like a working configuration for IPv4 but a broken configuration for IPv6.

Comment: I got this same issue with https://monitoredu.com today. The only way I was able to fix it (other then using my cell phone data instead of wifi) was to enable WPA3 on my wifi network. I can't explain why this worked but maybe someone else can.